# How to get data type of var

Tags: c#

I am trying to get a data type (`int`, `decimal` etc.) of a variable of `var {type}`:

```
var ratingSum = ratings.Sum(x=>x.Rating);//7
var ratingCount = ratings.Count();//2
decimal avgValue = decimal.Parse((ratingSum / ratingCount).ToString());//getting 3
var avgValue2 = (ratingSum / ratingCount).ToString(); //getting 3
```

I am unable to get exact value of `avgValue` or `avgValue2`  to check if it is of `int` or `decimal`. I always get 3 instead of 3.5.

If `ratingSum` is 8 and `ratingCount` is 2 my output should be 4 that means `avgValue` is of `int`.

Comment: The `GetType()` method can tell you the type of something.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want to know why you have incorrect result instead of getting types of `avgValue` and `avgValue2` (first is `decimal`, second is `string`). Here is explanation of your results.

Type of `ratingSum` is `int`, type of `ratingCount` is `int` too.

Division when both operands are `int` will produce `int` without fraction part of result. I.e. `7 / 2 = 3`. To have float result you can use this trick:

```
var avg = 1.0 * ratingSum / ratingCount; // 3.5
```

Comment: Well I change my var data type to int and multiplied result by 1.0 but still getting result 3

Comment: Please read my answer again. You need to multiple first operand, not result. If you will multiple `3` to `1.0` you will have `3.0`, not `3.5`.

Answer (score 0):

to get type of the variable you can use the following:

```
variable.GetType().Name;
```

Reference :[How can I get the data type of a variable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634079/how-can-i-get-the-data-type-of-a-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

An integer division always returns an integer, tending to zero, so for example this would be the results of the following divisions:

```cs
5 / 3 = 1 instead of 1.66
2 / 4 = 0 instead of 0.5
```

You can force .NET to use float division by casting one of the integer to float or double, so the examples would be have to be written like this:

```cs
(float) 5 / 3 = 1.66
(float) 2 / 4 = 0.5
```

You can see more in the MSDN documentation for the [division operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx)

There's an excellent answer for another StackOverflow question that explains why there's an integer division. 
[Why integer division in c# returns an integer but not a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10851273/why-integer-division-in-c-sharp-returns-an-integer-but-not-a-float)