# Use typeof with a variable

Tags: c#, types, gettype

`frmMainPage` is a Form in my project.

This is correct

```
var myType = typeof(frmMainPage);
```

This is incorrect

```
Form frm = (Form)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("frmMainPage"), _userName);

var myType = typeof(frm);
```

How can I use typeof with a variable?

Comment: Use `frm.GetType()` instead.  Do note that Type.GetType() already provided you with the type, so you just get back what you put in.  Smells like a vb.net conversion problem, but the whiff isn't strong enough to diagnose its evil default instance feature.

Comment: frm.GetType() is your friend..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the data type of a variable in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11634079/how-can-i-get-the-data-type-of-a-variable-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

`typeof` takes a type name you specify at compile time.

`GetType` gets the runtime type of an instance.